# Preserve set schedule/date in AlarmManager but stop repeat

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent, android-alarms

This code sets an alarm to fire at a specified day & time and repeats every 20 minutes.
Can I stop the repeat (when the user stops it or when it successfully performs a job) but keep the alarm set without having to reinitialize ?

Example, the following sets an alarm to fire at 8:30 am & repeats every 20 min after, if the user stops the alarm, I would like the alarm to fire the next day at 8:30 again

```
private AlarmManager alarmMgr;
private PendingIntent alarmIntent;
...
alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmListener.class);
alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, AlarmListener.REQUEST_CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

// Set the alarm to start at 8:30 am
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);

// 20 minutes repeating.
alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
        60 * 1000 * 20, alarmIntent);
```

A use case of this would be a monthly reminder where you set an Alarm for the 25th of every month. On the 25th, your Alarm would fire and repeat every 20 min but when you stop it, it should keep the schedule of firing an alarm on the 25th !

**Also,** any optimizations, notices or warnings regarding using AlarmManager would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can achieve that. My suggestion is your alarm manager, you set it to `setExact` and you also need to check if the calendar is today or not like below:

```
 //check whether the time is earlier than current time. If so, set it to tomorrow. Otherwise, all alarms for earlier time will fire
 if (calendar.before(now)) {
     calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1)
 }
 val timeTrigger = calendar.timeInMillis

 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
     alarmManagerActivity.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(
         AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
         timeTrigger, //timeTrigger is Systemtimeinmillis
         pendingIntentActivity
      )
  } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
         alarmManagerActivity.setExact(
         AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
         timeTrigger,
         pendingIntentActivity
     )
  } else {
       alarmManagerActivity[AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeTrigger] = pendingIntentActivity
  }
```

Separate the method `AlarmManager` for 8:30PM with the `AlarmManager` repeat for 20minutes. Make sure you use the same `BroadcastReceiver` so it will just trigger here for both of them. See example at below:

```
fun alarmManager20Minutes(context: Context) {
    val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    calendar[Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY] = 0
    calendar[Calendar.MINUTE] = 0
    calendar[Calendar.SECOND] = 0
    val intent = Intent(context, BroadcastReceiverHealthDeclaration::class.java)
    val timeTrigger = System.currentTimeMillis() + 20 * 60 * 1000 //20 mins
    val pendingIntentActivity = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
        context,
        ALARM_MANAGER_ID_20_MINUTES,
        intent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
    )
    val alarmManagerActivity = context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        alarmManagerActivity.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(
            AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            timeTrigger,
            pendingIntentActivity
        )
    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
        alarmManagerActivity.setExact(
            AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            timeTrigger,
            pendingIntentActivity
        )
    } else {
        alarmManagerActivity[AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeTrigger] = pendingIntentActivity
    }
}
```

Next, at your `BroadcastReceiver`, `onReceive`, once it trigger 8.30AM for today, you need to call the your `Alarm Manager` method again and also don't forget to call `alarmManager20Minutes()`.

```
override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
    //Check if user want to receive the daily or not
    val receiveNotification = QuickSave.instance.getBoolean(
        Constant.RECEIVE_NOTIFICATION,
        true
    )
    if (receiveNotification) {
        AlarmManagerUtil.alarmManager20Minutes(context)
        //And then call method for 8:30AM
        AlarmManagerUtil.alarmManager830AM(context)
    }
}
```

So, when `onReceive` triggered, so you call method `alarmManager20minutes`. It will call again `onReceive` for next 20minutes and also it will set the `alarmManager830AM` for next day.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but basically what I wanted to know if it could be achieved with only one instance instead of running multiple Alarm Managers !

Answer (score 1):

Of course this is possible. When you want to reschedule the alarm to start at 8:30 am the next day just do this:

```
// Set the alarm to start at 8:30 am next day
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY, 1);

// 20 minutes repeating.
alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 
        calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 60 * 1000 * 20, alarmIntent);
```

This will replace your repeating alarm with an alarm that goes off tomorrow at 8:30am and then repeats every 20 mins after that.

Comment: Yeah I basically have to call the alarm again to replace the original. I thought maybe there was a way without having to call again.